# Java JPMS project : package (JAXB) is not visible

Tags: java-platform-module-system

I am creating my first project using JPMS . Simply I have a Maven project and some simple classes that need JAXB classes.Then

1. created module-info.java

   module mymodule{

   requires jakarta.xml.bind;
   requires java.base;
   requires java.xml;
   }
2. added JAXB dependencies in pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>savino.prove.view</groupId>
    <artifactId>View</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>savino.prove.view.View</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       
        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAXB Implementation -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
            <plugins>  
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>20</source>
                        <target>20</target>  
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

but on JAXBUtils class I got compilation error :

package jakarta.xml.bind is not visible
(package jakarta.xml.bind is declared in the unnamed module, but module mymodule does not read it

nevertheless I see jakarta.xml.bind package in the dependency and also (for example) JAXBContext class .
ALso ,maven use correctly the module path parameter :

> Command line options:
> -d /home/devuser/work/Prove/CSGView/View/target/classes -classpath /home/devuser/work/Prove/CSGView/View/target/classes: --module-path /home/devuser/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/home/devuser/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar: -sourcepath /home/devuser/work/Prove/CSGView/View/src/main/java:/home/devuser/work/Prove/CSGView/View/target/generated-sources/annotations: -s /home/devuser/work/Prove/CSGView/View/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -target 20 -source 20 -encoding UTF-8 --module-version 1.0

The project structure is :
[image: NB project structure]

I saw this [Baeldung JPMS example](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module-project-java-jpms), and starting investigate my problem also with this example because it report same errors underlined by NB Ide ,but the mainappmodule is working, I can run it !
Then is just NB showing wrong compile errors ?
Look the image :
[image: NB red underling the example project]

Comment: Looks like jaxb is on the class path, not module path.

Comment: maven report ,as command line option :  --module-path /home/devuser/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/4.0.0/jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar:/home/devuser/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.0/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar      This doesn't mean JPMS have to look at my local repository ?